# SQL calculate percentage in a special case

Tags: sql, database

```
select 
    RESTAURANT, 
    RANK, 
    (select count(SCORE) 
     from TRIPADVISOR 
     where score = 4) as totalfour, 
    (select count(*) 
     from TRIPADVISOR) as total   
from 
    TRIPADVISOR
```

I know there is an average function for SQL. My question is that I have a TRIPADVISOR table which consists of columns of Resturant names, rank (1-10), SCORE reviewed by customers(1-5). I want to calculate the percentage of the total amount of people who gave a 4 for score by the total number of elements which would be count(*). How would I be able to do that? I have it set up where I am doing two subqueries in the select clause which shows total number of people who gave a 4 and the total number of entries which is count(*) along with the list of Resturant names and all the ranks. Thanks.

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with a counted `CASE`

```
SELECT
 RESTAURANT, 
 RANK, 
 ((COUNT(CASE WHEN score = 4 THEN 1 END) * 1.0) / COUNT(*))*100 AS PercentageScore4
FROM TRIPADVISOR
GROUP BY RESTAURANT, RANK;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want this per restaurant:

```
select restaurant,
       avg(case when score = 4 then 1.0 else 0 end) as avg_4
from TRIPADVISOR 
group by restaurant;
```

If you want this over the entire database:

```
select avg(case when score = 4 then 1.0 else 0 end) as avg_4
from TRIPADVISOR ;
```

If you want this appended to each row, then use window functions:

```
select restaurant,
       avg(case when score = 4 then 1.0 else 0 end) over (partition by restaurant) as avg_4_restaurant,
       avg(case when score = 4 then 1.0 else 0 end) over () as avg_4_overall
from TRIPADVISOR ;
```